# Adding class to php file

Tags: php, android, web-scraping, google-play

I just want to display the Android app details. Here I found one source from github called [MarketBot](https://github.com/pastfuture/MarketBot). In my php file I have created code like

```
use PastFuture\MarketBot\Android\GooglePlay;
$market = new PastFuture\MarketBot\Android\GooglePlay;
$response = $market->get('com.aol.mobile.engadget', 'apps');
var_dump($response);
exit;
```

Whenever I run my php file it shows the error **Class 'PastFuture\MarketBot\Android\GooglePlay' not found**

What can I do to get out from this error.

Comment: download `GooglePlay.php` or if its your own file place it at `root/PastFuture/MarketBot/Android/`

Comment: Acutally I have done this, but still I'm not getting it.